# Converting between exchange rates

Tags: algorithms

Suppose I have a currency exchange rate of 1 USD = 102.642499 JPY.

If I had 50 USD and wanted to get the value in JPY using that exchange rate, my equation would be 102.642499 * 50, correct?

How about in reverse, in which I had 50 JPY and wanted to know the value in USD?

I know this seems preposterously simple, but somehow my brain is stalling on it.

Comment: If you have 50 USD, change them to 1 USD bills. Thus, you have an equivalent of 50 * 1 USD. If 1 USD = 102.642499 JPY, then……

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example,

$1 JPY = 1 / 102.642499 USD  = 0.00974255 USD$ (This is called the Reverse Conversion Rate)

$50 JPY = 0.48712766 USD$

Answer (score 1):

It’s really simple. You just told us that $\$=102.642499\yen$. Now just solve for the letter $\yen$, by dividing both sides of the equation by $102.642499\,$, and there you have the answer given by @Rao A.